# What does the post() method do on a DeletionMixin in the Django source code?

Tags: django, django-models

I am learning Django and trying to understand `DeleteView` from first principals.

In the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/979f61abd322507aafced9627702362e541ec34e/django/views/generic/edit.py#L202) for the `DeletionMixin` there is both a `delete` method and a `post` method:

```
class DeletionMixin:
    """Provide the ability to delete objects."""
    success_url = None

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Call the delete() method on the fetched object and then redirect to the
        success URL.
        """
        self.object = self.get_object()
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        self.object.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)

    # Add support for browsers which only accept GET and POST for now.
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

What is the difference between these two methods and when are they called?

Is the `delete()` method only called on a `request.GET`?

If a `delete()` method is also defined on a `models.Model` class does this do something different, override the `DeletionMixin` in the view or something else?

E.g:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def delete(self):
        ...
        return
```

**Please could you help me understand the logical "workflow" of what is happening in when `DeleteView` is called.**

Relevant class constructs below:

```
class BaseDeleteView(DeletionMixin, BaseDetailView):
    pass


class DeleteView(SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin, BaseDeleteView):
    template_name_suffix = '_confirm_delete'
```

Answer (score 0):

this means that DeletionMixin only respond to a 'delete' or 'post' Http method.

By definition: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

HTTP Methods are GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS

**GET** is used to request data from a specified resource.

**POST** is used to send data to a server to create/update a resource.

**DELETE** method deletes the specified resource.

Therefore, **GET** Method is not intended for Create/Update or Delete actions..
that's the reason why DeletionMixin does not implements a method for GET request.

In other words, in order to DELETE something,  you have to use a **POST** or **DELETE** http methods in the request. Most of the time, you will use a POST.